# How to bind a List<string[]> to a DataGridView control?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a list of string array and I'd like it to be bind to DataGridView.

Code snippet that I tried -

```
 var userNphotoValues = new List<string[]>();
 userNphotoValues.Add(new[] { stringAVal, stringBVal });

 dataGridView.DataSource = userNphotoValues;
```

I am getting result as shown in snapshot -

[image: After binding result]

I expect output to be as follow -

[image: Expected output]

Can you please help me how I can bind those values to datagridview?

Comment: What's wrong with what you're showing us?  Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: You should put your xaml and there you should describe what you want to see there.

Comment: @All, I want to display *stringAVal* under **User** column and *stringBVal* under **PhotoPath**. The rest of columns are auto generated and I don't know why.

Comment: Wow, that's seriously what you wanted us to guess?  Please update your question to be more clear, or it will be closed.

Comment: @GrantWinney You're right, I confused it with WPF.

Comment: @roryap I had edited the question. I can't think what more required. Please let me know what details, you think , I am missing.

Comment: Looks better now, but I would suggest you **clearly state** what is wrong instead of asking people to guess by looking at a screen shot.  E.g. "The username and photo path are missing".

Comment: @roryap I agree. It's just that I thought in other context. I will take care of it. Thanks for suggestions. I note it down.

Comment: Why do you insist on using `string[]`? Can't you just create an anonymous object, for example?

Comment: In your first screenshot, you are seeing the auto generated columns because you are binding the source to arrays, therefore each property of that array is resolved to a column.  You can verify this: `userNphotoValues[0].` IntelliSense will reveal those exact properties; `Length`, `LongLength`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = userNphotoValues
    .Select(arr => new { UserName = arr[0], PhotoPath = arr[1] })
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

Alexander Petrov's answer is great.  This is simply an alternative:

Create an object class and replace your string array with this object, then bind normally. (In this case you would not need to pre-create your columns.)

```
public class UserPhotoInfo
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
}

var userNphotoValues = new List<UserPhotoInfo>();
userNphotoValues.Add(new UserPhotoInfo() { Username = stringAVal, PhotoPath = stringBVal });

dataGridView.DataSource = userNphotoValues;
```